# How can I delete user details of database in SQL Server 2012

Tags: database, sql-server-2012

I am sorry, maybe this is simple question but I didn't figure it out. I am new to database side, I created a database `Freshtime` with user details (`User Name:Infratab`). I backup my entire database and send to one of my colleague.

I assign the following rules to `Infratab` (User)

```
General:
     Default Schema : dbo
Owned Schema :
      db_ddladmin,db_owner
Membership :
      None
```

He restored `Freshtime` on his system, and he wants to delete user details in his system, so he asked me to delete user details in my system and re-again send backup file. I said okay.

But I am unable to delete user details.I am getting the following error.

```
the database principal owns a schema and cannot be dropped error 15138
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have `SQL Server Management Studio` installed,

- In the `Object Explorer` pane, expand `Databases`
- Expand database `Freshtime`
- Expand `Security`
- Expand `Users`
- Right-click on user `Infratab` and select `Delete`
- Click `Ok` in the `Delete User` dialog box

Comment: Thanks `@Luis LL`I tried like that,it's not working. I found the solution.Sorry I didn't mention what I faced error message.So I will update my question then I will post answer.

Comment: I posted my answer, check it once.